# Finding items in lists using the in operator

Tags: python, list, input

I created some code where I try to find elements in a list given by the user using the in operator.

```
productNums = []

nums = int(input("How many numbers should be in your list?"))

while nums > 0:
    productNums.append(input("Add a number: "))  
    nums -= 1

numFind = int(input("What number are you trying to find? "))

if numFind in productNums:
    print("This product number is in the list")
elif numFind not in productNums:
    print("Ahh, sorry. This product number is NOT in this list!")
else:
    print("Huh, you're confusing me now, check your numbers pal!")
```

When I run this, I get the outcome that the number is not in this list, even though it is in it. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Typo.  You are converting `numFind` to `int`, but you have left the `productNums` as strings.

Comment: `productNums.append(input("Add a number: "))` is the problem here - you don't cast the input to an int, so it gets added to `productNums` as a string, and then when you ask for `numFind`, you cast it to an `int` so you're trying to find an int among a list of strings.

Comment: ```productNums.append(int(input("Add a number: ")))``` should do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As people said above, just small issue with you integers and strings.
This is your code working:
Be careful with the indentention, initially was a mess.

```
productNums = []

nums = int(input("How many numbers should be in your list?"))

while nums > 0:
    productNums.append(int(input("Add a number: ")))  
    nums -= 1

    numFind = int(input("What number are you trying to find? "))

    if numFind in productNums:
      print("This product number is in the list")
    elif numFind not in productNums:
      print("Ahh, sorry. This product number is NOT in this list!")
    else:
      print("Huh, you're confusing me now, check your numbers pal!")
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe its a missing conversion when u append, its appended as a string and u search for an int

Answer (score 0):

Because the productNums list contains string values, not integer, so you always compare int with str variable and obtain the same result. Set productNums elements to `int` and it will work properly.

```
productNums = []

nums = int(input("How many numbers should be in your list?"))

while nums > 0:
    productNums.append(int(input("Add a number: ")))  
    nums -= 1

numFind = int(input("What number are you trying to find? "))

if numFind in productNums:
    print("This product number is in the list")
elif numFind not in productNums:
    print("Ahh, sorry. This product number is NOT in this list!")
else:
    print("Huh, you're confusing me now, check your numbers pal!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You correctly cast `nums` and `numFind` to `int`, but you didn't do so for the input values in the `while` loop — so `productNums` is a list of single-character strings.

This change will fix it:

```
    productNums.append(int(input("Add a number: ")))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to find an int in a list of strings.

When you wrote the code `productNums.append(input("Add a number: "))`, after the user enters the code, the number would be appended into the `productNums` list *as a string*.

Further on, the  `numFind = int(input("What number are you trying to find? "))` makes the user enter a number. this time, the input is converted into an *int*. So when the line of code `if numFind in productNums:` runs, it sees the `if` as the user trying to find an `int` in a list of `strings`.

In short, you should either change the `productNums.append(input("Add a number: "))` code into `productNums.append(int(input("Add a number: ")))`, or change the line of code `numFind = int(input("What number are you trying to find? "))` into `numFind = input("What number are you trying to find? ")`.